# Overwrite data using COPY from in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cqlsh, cassandra-3.0

How to overwrite data using COPY from command in Cassandra. 
Would help to know for different cqlsh versions.

Looks to be we can as per cassandra-3.0 
 https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/latest/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html?hl=copy

Comment: What do you mean by overwrite ? provide an example

Comment: What @AshrafulIslam has said. In any case Cassandra will always upsert (insert or update) your data regardless whether record already exists or not.